# Split lines by polygons PostGIS

Tags: postgis, splitting, overlay

I have lines that I would like to split at polygon boundaries. The line table is MULTI and the polygon table is MULTI and was derived from a MULTILINESTRING table that was buffered then unioned to create one geometry.

The pink is the polygon and the white lines are what needs to be split at the polygon boundaries.

[image]

This is the returned geometry after running my query. Note the missing geoms, both inside and outside of the polygon, relative to the first pic.

[image]

I am almost there but my query is not returning all the lines that are in my original table and I can't figure out why.

```
CREATE TABLE split As

WITH dmp_geom As ( -- used to dump from MULTILINESTRING to LINESTRING
SELECT (ST_Dump(multiline.geom)).geom As dmp_geom
FROM multiline
),

split_geom As ( --splitting dumped lines at polygon boundaries
SELECT ST_Split(t1.dmp_geom, t2.geom) As split_geom
FROM dmp_geom t1, unioned_poly t2 
)

SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(split_geom, 2) As geom --select only lines
FROM split_geom;
```

My question is: how can adjust my query so that I will get all the features in my original table, just split at the polygon boundaries?

Comment: I'm not sure the pink line is a polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why the strange behavior described in the question occurred, but I did fix the problem. I was able to get the expected geometries returned by simply converting the multilines to single geometries.

After that, this code block successfully split the lines at the polygon boundaries:

```
CREATE TABLE split.split As

WITH split As (
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(t1.geom, t2.geom))).geom As split_geom
FROM lines t1, poly t2 
) 

--select only lines from geom collection that resulted from ST_Dump()
SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(split_geom, 2) As geom 
FROM split;

-- redefine geom col to LINESTRING
ALTER TABLE split.split
ALTER COLUMN split_geom TYPE geometry (linestring,3857) 
USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and you're solution didn't fix it.

I first found a workaround splitting the multilines twice : it worked better, but the split were not always precisely at the intersection with the multipolygons boundaries.

In the end, I found out another option, very much efficient and faster if you have a gist index on both tables. In my case, I just need the pieces of multilines *inside* the multipolygons, this way :

```
SELECT ST_MakeValid(ST_Intersection(l.geom, p.geom)) as geom
FROM multilines l, multipolygons p
WHERE ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
```

If you need to keep all the lines, but splitted, this should do the job :

```
SELECT ST_MakeValid(ST_Intersection(l.geom, p.geom)) as geom
FROM multilines l, multipolygons p
WHERE ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
UNION
SELECT ST_MakeValid(ST_Difference(l.geom, p.geom)) as geom
FROM multilines l, multipolygons p
```

You can add in the SELECT statement the fields you want to keep from tables l and p